# Does iOS 9 Notes no longer sync with more recent versions of iOS/Mac OS

Tags: data-synchronization, notes.app

I have an old iPad running iOS 9.3.5 (the latest version that the hardware will support). I also use an iPhone (iOS 12.2) an iMac (High Sierra) and a MacBook Pro (also High Sierra).

Notes sync perfectly through iCloud between the Macs and the iPhone. However, the sync seems one-directional when it comes to the iPad. Text changes (including note creation/deletion) that I make on one of the other devices are sent to the iPad, but changes made on the iPad are not sent back to the other devices. This can lead to some very weird text on the iPad, as if parts of the text (rather than a complete note) are being stored locally, and *combined* with the text that is synced via iCloud. The result, on the iPad, is a jumbled mess.

I am presuming that this is because of the changes made and extra features added to Notes app in more recent versions (in both iOS and Mac OS) that prevents syncing from taking place properly, and that there's nothing I can do about it, but **can somebody confirm this**? All the results I found from googling relate to the opposite situation: a newer version of iOS failing to sync with an old version of Mac OS, which is not precisely the scenario that I have here.

Comment: It works fine for me: iPad mini 1 with iOS 9.3.5, iPhone 6S with iOS 12.2, Mac Air with El Capitan.

Comment: @lhf Hmm. El Cap is a couple of OSes behind my Mac OS machines, so I wonder if that's why it works for you and not for me? Each  new major version of Mac OS adds new stuff to it (High Sierra added tables, I think) and although there is typically resilience with inter-version syncing (my phone had support for tables before my Mac did, IIRC, and notes using the newer formatting feature would look weird in the older OS) it may be that eventually the combined weight of multiple rounds of new features breaks it. I can't find any confirmation online, though.